# Issuing prepared/parameterized queries through libcouchbase-cxx

Tags: c++, couchbase, libcouchbase

I'm brand new to couchbase, and I'm developing a client which needs to issue prepared/parameterized n1ql queries via the c++ client library (https://github.com/couchbaselabs/libcouchbase-cxx). Issuing static queries is straightforward, but I haven't been able to find the correct process for issuing prepared queries. Has anybody been able to do this?

Comment: Note that libcouchbase-cxx is an unsupported, experimental client library.

Answer (score 1):

Following doc/example shows how to use the prepared stmt.

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/c/n1ql-queries-with-sdk.html
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/server-4.5/c/query-placeholders.cc

```
// To enable using prepared (optimized) statements, you can use
// the LCB_CMDN1QL_F_PREPCACHE flag. This is equivalent to setting
// 'adhoc=False' in other SDKs
cmd.cmdflags |= LCB_CMDN1QL_F_PREPCACHE;
rc = lcb_n1p_mkcmd(params, &cmd);
rc = lcb_n1ql_query(instance, &rows, &cmd);
lcb_wait(instance);
```

-Prasad